# Why does the quantile function of bivariate normal variables become non-elementary in one dimension?

Tags: intuition, error-function, quantile-function

I have been studying a bivariate random process where $X \sim N(0, \sigma_x), Y \sim N(0, \sigma_y)$.  It turns out that finding [an ellipse that covers proportion *p* of samples on this process is given by elementary functions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/629035/34792): Its semi-axes are $a = \sigma_x \sqrt{-2 \ln(1-p)}$ and $b = \sigma_y \sqrt{-2 \ln(1-p)}$.

However, the analogue in one dimension is not so elegant: The interval that covers proportion *p* of just one of the variables (say *X*) is given by $\sigma_x \sqrt{2} \text{erf}^{-1}(p)$.

My naive intuition is that this *p*-interval in one dimension should be the limit of the *p*-ellipse in two dimensions as $\sigma_y \rightarrow 0$.  But given the formulas above this does not appear to be the case.

Why is the one dimensional covering interval not the limit of the two-dimensional covering ellipse?  Or is it, and it can be shown that the formulas for the ellipse axes collapse to the (non-elementary) inverse error function in the limit?